# how to search Twitter APi and filter by number of favorites

Tags: python, search, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use the Twitter search API, and get only tweets with at least 10 favorites. I couldn't find any documentation on such a search operator. Is the only way to search all tweets and filter the results?

I'm using python with Tweepy.